# Getting a custom claim from JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I'm trying in to get a custom claim from JWT token in Spring Boot. I am able to get the subject as below:

```
public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token,  Claims::getSubject);
}
public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}
```

I tried  this

```
public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token,  Claims::get("name of the token"));
}
```

This didn't work. The function get is like getSubjet present under io.jsonwebtoken.claims.

Comment: `Claims::get("name of the token")` is not a valid method reference. Try this: `claims -> claims.get("name of the token", String.class)`.